# Mapping :nohlsearch to escape key

Tags: vim

I like to use `hlsearch` but I hate to keep everything highlighted after searching, to solve this problem I could simply use `:nohlsearch` or an abbreviation of it but that is still to much effort so I decided to try to do that on pressing escape. What I came up with is:

```
nnoremap <ESC> :nohlsearch<CR>
```

This works exactly as I want it to in GVim which I usually use for development but it does not work in vim.

If I search something in vim, press escape to deactivate the highlighting and use one of the arrow keys to navigate vim goes directly into insert mode and inserts a character on a new line.

As I never really came around to using `h`, `j`, `k` and `l` for navigation this is really annoying and I would like to know how I can make vim behave like gvim.

If you need more information you can find my entire vim configuration [here](http://github.com/DasIch/vimfiles).

Comment: Ctrl-L is already used to redraw the screen, so I use that:
`nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :nohl<CR><C-l>`

Comment: I have mapped \ for :nohlsearch^M (\ as opposite looking of /; plus easy to remember as just above the enter key.)

Comment: @idbrii, excellent suggestion, thank you.  In addition it prevents the problem of hitting e.g. `5` then pressing `<Esc>` to cancel, and getting `E481: No range allowed`.

Comment: @Wildcard: To solve that specific problem with your mappings, use `:<C-u>` instead of `:`   like this `nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :<C-u>nohl<CR><C-l>` That will clear the range that's automatically inserted (try typing `5:` in normal mode and you'll see the range that's causing that error).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that when you press `<Up>` terminal sends something like `<Esc>OA` (you will see it if you type `<C-v><Up>` in insert mode) which is remapped to `:nohlsearch<CR>OA`. I do not know any solution except not mapping a single `<Esc>`, try either mapping to double `<Esc>`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I checked what the terminal sends and used that to solve the problem by mapping those.

Answer (score 0):

I created this map to disable search when press double `<Esc>`

```
nnoremap <silent> <Esc><Esc> :let @/ = ""<CR>
```

Answer (score -5):

is `:noh` still too much work?

**EDIT**: I don't know about you, but I personally think :noh is easier than pressing Esc key, since I can press all the buttons without stretching my pinky too far (which is why I think the default mapping of Esc for going back to Command Mode from Insert Mode is a bit unfortunate). If you really use the :nohlsearch that much, you probably should remap it to something you can reach from the Home Area (i.e. regular letters, or numbers, or perhaps Ctrl-letters).

Anyway, typing the exact command you give works in my vim (on gnome-terminal). Are you sure you put the rule in .vimrc file, instead of .gvimrc? No luck after restarting vim? Try `:source /path/to/config/file` and see if that makes it to work.

Comment: "or an abbreviation". `:noh` takes four letters my preferred solution only one. That may sound a little bit stupid to some people but I search often enough for things that this matters to me.

Comment: I have escape ond caps lock because indeed the time required to reach the escape key is far too long.

Comment: @Daslch: likewise, that's why we choose vim.